# Need help making login page with salts

Tags: php, mysql, hash, salt

Alright, I'm trying to make a login page. It seems that all of the pages worked pretty good- until I added salts. I don't really understand them, but doing something as basic as I am shouldn't be to hard to figure out. Here's "loginusr.php":

```
<html>
<body>
<?php  

//form action = index.php

session_start();

include("mainmenu.php");  

$usrname  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usrname']);    
$pass     = $_POST['password'];  
$salt     = $pass;
$password = sha1($salt.$pass);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "g00dfor@boy");
if(!$con)
{
    die("Unable to establish connection with host. We apologize for any inconvienience.");
}

mysql_select_db("users", $con) or die("Can't connect to database.");

$select = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE usrname='$usrname' and password='$password'";
$query  = mysql_query($select);
$verify = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($verify==1)
{
    $_SESSION["valid_user"] = $usrname;
    header("location:index.php");
}    
else
{
    echo "Wrong username or password. Please check that CAPS LOCK is off.";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Back to login</a>";
} 

mysql_close($con);    
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

I used the command `echo $password;` to show me if the password in the database matched with the script. They did. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see you remembered to use `mysql_real_escape_string`. :)

Comment: Ken - You need to use mysql_real_escape_string on the password as well. :-)

Comment: yeah. People rode me on that constantly when I was starting out.

Comment: do you have more than one matching row by chance? I see you say if verify==1, what if verify==2?

Comment: @middaparka, while it is surely a good idea to escape everything or use prepared statements, $password is the result sha1() so cannot contain any injection in the current code.

Comment: i meant to spell username like that

Comment: What is your magic quotes setting on the server?  Can you echo the $select to check that it's what you think it is?

Comment: well, i cant have more than one matching row- i took care of that in the registration script.

Comment: @nhnb True, probably overkill in this instance. Good practice that said, and it can't hurt.

Comment: @SRM first of all, i was able to use the program before (when i didnt add salt), so yes, select does work. its just if a try to do the salt, it doesnt work.

Comment: @Ken obviously it doesn't work.  Adding the salt does nothing magical, you are just concatenating two strings.  If the password from the hash matches the password in the dictionary then something is wrong with your select statement.  Maybe there is a single quote in the hashed string?  Thats why I suggested echoing it out.  It's a matter of echo $select and you will know one way or the other without guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've misunderstood salts, since you're setting `$salt` to be the password.

A salt should be a completely random string that's stored in a user record along with the password hash. A new unique salt should be generated for every user. So you need to add a new column to your database, called "password_salt" or similar.

Rather than trying to use the password in the `SELECT` query and see if you get any records, you actually need to just `SELECT` using the username/user_id in order to get the password hash and salt so that you can then use those to determine if the user entered the correct password.

When you sign up new users you should add the fields with values like this,

```
<?php
// This is registeruser.php

$salt = substr(sha1(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 20);
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$pass_to_store = hash("sha256", $salt.$pass);

// Then issue a DB query to store the $salt and $pass_to_store in the user record.
// Do not store $pass, you don't need it.
// e.g. INSERT INTO users ('username', 'password_salt', 'password_hash') VALUES (:username, :salt, :pass_to_store);
?>
```

Then to check the password is the same when logging in, you do something like this,

```
<?php
// This is loginuser.php

$user = // result from SQL query to retrieve user record
// e.g. SELECT password_hash, password_salt FROM users WHERE username='from_user'

$salt_from_db = $user['password_salt'];
$pass_from_db = $user['password_hash'];
if ($pass_from_db == hash("sha256", $salt_from_db.$_POST['password'])
{
    // Password matches!
}
?>
```

Don't forget to sanitize user inputs and anything you're putting into your database. You might want to look into using prepared statements instead of having to remember to use `mysql_real_escape_string` all the time.

Comment: ill try it your way. sit tight.

Comment: Make sure to see my update, I got the check the wrong way around in the last bit of code, doh! Obviously I've not had enough caffeine today.

Comment: oh... i get it, this makes the salt unique for each record, making it more secure!

Comment: Indeed. The idea of the salt is to prevent rainbow table attacks. If you just hash a password on it's own, an attacker can construct a table of lots of dictionary words and their hashes and just use that to get the original password from the hash for every user in your database. If you have a unique salt for each user it would mean an attacker would have to preconstruct a different lookup table for every single user since each one has their own salt.

Comment: hold on, i accidentally deleted phpmyadmin.

Comment: it doesn't insert the data into the db

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with your INSERT INTO db query. Check for typos, etc. I've added some example queries into my answer. You won't be able to cut/paste these directly into your code but they should give you enough of an idea so you can modify them for your data model.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're salting with the same password?  Normally a salt would be a random key that is specific to your site that you prepend to the password input, which it looks like you're doing fine.  Just make sure you're using that same salt for checking that you use when the password is created.

Also, to use sessions properly you need to have session_start before anything is output to the page:

```
<?php

session_start();

?>
<html>
<body>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A salt is a random value to prevent an attacker from just looking up the source of a hash in table generated based on common passwords. (Using the username as salt is obviously not a good idea as it only adds very little entropy).

So you need to store the salt in the database and read it from the database in order to calculate the salted password hash for comparison with the stored value.

You misspelled username a couple of times, is it misspelled in the database, too?

Comment: yeah its spelled like that in the database.

Comment: but if the password matches with the password in the db, shouldn't verify return as 1?